# How to adjust cell height according to content?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

i am making status app for ios and using my WordPress Website to fetch data. everything is working fine but the problem is content, I am using UIlabel to display status in cell. but the problem is cell's height is fixed and not getting larger according to the content.

this is my code in CollectionViewCell

```
func setup(with image: Post) {
  let htmlEncodedString = String(htmlEncodedString: image.content.rendered)
               statusText.text = htmlEncodedString
}
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
       setNeedsLayout()
       layoutIfNeeded()
       let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
       var frame = layoutAttributes.frame
        frame.size.height = ceil(size.height)
       layoutAttributes.frame = frame
       return layoutAttributes
   }
```

In label constraints i have added top, bottom, left and right

[image]

i have added this inside ViewDidLoad in ViewController

```
 let layout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
                   layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
                   layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width-20, height: 40)
```

and sizeForItemAt

```
if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height > 960 {
                               returnValue = CGSize(width: (((view.frame.width) - 40) / 2), height: 100)
                           } else {
                               returnValue = CGSize(width: view.frame.width - 20 , height: 100)
                           }
```

please help!